# How to compile Bootstrap Less correct?

Tags: css, less

What is the right order of compiling Bootstrap Less files? I have some external Less files too and want to compile all into one.

Should I take at first bootstrap.less or start with the custom.less?

1. bootstrap.less
2. bootstrap-extend.less
3. base.less
4. site.less
5. ...

By this Order the Custom Design bootstrap-extend.less, base.less and site.less has no priority and will not be shown in layout. If I am changing the order than it has double classes and CSS is grown.

[image]

Comment: Usually you do not compile Less files *separately*. It should be one "master" file that imports all others (at least those it depends on). You can compile independent projects (e.g. Bootstrap and Font-Awesome) separately (assuming you're going to merge resulting CSS files if you need only one in the end), but in this case the order does not matter.

Comment: put your new files at the end of this file, and compile this file: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less

Comment: Added some more Information

Comment: Is this WE? If so the problem is not really in the order of compilation but in it's general config. By default WE is set up to compile each Less file in the project separately (which gives an illusion of easy-to-use), but this is simply wrong method for any complex project. Probably you need to search some WE-related questions here for some hints (it's hard to provide you with concrete guidelines w/o seeing exact structure of your Less code - in particular all the `@import`s there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the npm bootstrap package and compile it with the tool of choice (grunt or any less compiler you like). You can download it from the [bootstrap Getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) page.

Your customizations can be made in `variables.less` and `bootstrap-theme.less`. Edit them, and overwrite the original ones with yours before compiling the `bootstrap.less`. This will integrate your customizaton in the `bootstrap.css/.css.min` files. Any other styling very specific for your project should be done in a separate file. In this way you can easyly upgrade the bootstrap version. You can use .less for this, and @import the same `variables.less`, and the original `mixins.less` to simplify your coding. For example, you can use mixings to create custom buttons, using colors defined in `variables.less`.

There is an interesting tool to prepare this files: http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/ Once you finish, you can download both files, but beware of downloading the files that contain all the variables, not only the modified ones (modify it on this toolsconfiguration).

The final step could be concatenating and minifying all the .css files in a single one. You can use grunt or any other tool for this.